# Why promise chains can be flattened?

Tags: javascript, promise

The following code contains two kinds of promise chain, seems they'r equivalent, but I don't understand why they are equivalent. I think of it like  2*(3+4) = 2*3+4, which is not correct.

```
// example1
runAsync1()
.then(function(data1){
    return runAsync2()
    .then(function(data2){
        return runAsync3(); 
    })
})
.then(function(data3){
    console.log(data3);
});

// example 2
runAsync1()
.then(function(data1){
    return runAsync2();
}).then(function(data2){
    return runAsync3();  
}).then(function(data3){
    console.log(data3);
});
```

Comment: *"I think of it like 2*(3+4) = 2*3+4"* - To me it looks more like comparing (2+3) + 4 with 2 + 3 + 4.

Comment: So why it's not '2*(3+4) = 2*3+4'?

Comment: Because the first one has the `.then()`s in the same order as the second one. The first one's first `.then()` doesn't return `runAsync2()`, it returns `runAsync2().then(...)`.

Comment: *"but what if?"* - That new example is too hard to read in an unformatted comment. Anyway, just because *some* promise chains can be flattened doesn't mean that *all* promise chains can be flattened exactly the same way. If one of the `.then()`s did something strange or returned the wrong thing you would get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit implementation-specific, but the magic, regardless of the specifics is in the `then`.

Then does a couple of things.
The TL;DR is that `then` subscribes to returned promise chains, but below are examples closer to the guts of a promise.

The first thing is:
*"Is the promise still pending? Then schedule these callbacks for later; otherwise, schedule this callback to run on the next tick (`setTimeout(handle, 0)`). Return a new promise that resolves/rejects to the eventual value."*

```
// basically accurate-ish
then (onSuccess, onError) {
  return new Promise((resolveNext, rejectNext) => {
    if (myPromiseIsDone) {
      // I already have the value; run the next step ASAP
      // this is ugly, but hopefully it proves a point
      runOnNextTick(onSuccess, onError, promiseResult, resolveNext, rejectNext);
    } else {
      // I don't have a result yet; come back when it's ready
      scheduleWhenDone(onSuccess, onError, resolveNext, rejectNext);
    }
  });
}
```

The second is where your answer lies:
*"Run the handler. Get the return value from the callback passed to `then`. Is the return value a Thenable object (has a `then` method)? Then call `then` and pass in the resolve/reject functions that control my promise... otherwise, resolve/reject accordingly, based on whether it throws or returns."*

```
// entirely subjective and implementation-specific,
// but the algorithm is almost spec-compliant
handleSuccess (onSuccess, resolveNext, rejectNext, value) {
  if (!onSuccess) {
    // if they didn't give me a `then(callback)`,
    // just pass the value to the next promise
    resolveNext(value);
    return;
  }
  try {
    // I'm running the `then(callback)` here
    const result = onSuccess(value);
    if (hasThenMethod(result)) {
      // it's promise-like, subscribe
      result.then(resolveNext, rejectNext);
    } else {
      resolveNext(result);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // something blew up, while trying to succeed, so fail
    rejectNext(err);
  }
}
```

Reject looks similar.

So the outer `then` subscribes to the inner `then`.

If you ever wanted to get into functional programming, the ES6 `Promise` is *almost* a monad.
The difference is that a monad would force you to have a different method, to tell it to chain to the returned promise, rather than doing it automatically.
`then` is basically the same as `map` on arrays. You call then, pass it a function that gets the value and returns a new promise with the transformed value.

So a monadic promise might be one that has `map` and `chain`, or `then` and `chain`, where `chain` does almost exactly the same thing but says "hey, `then`, this callback is going to return a promise; subscribe to that one, so that you flatten it out, rather than returning a promise of a promise of a value".

That's almost all it would take to be a monad.

Hope that all helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some braces would help you understand this a little better. (NOTE: this is exactly the same thing as you had except with an extra set of braces on the return)

```
// example1
runAsync1()
.then(function(data1){
    return (
        runAsync2()
        .then(function(data2){
            return runAsync3(); 
        })
    )
})
.then(function(data3){
    console.log(data3);
});
```

So what is happening here,

1. `.then` is called on `runAsynch1()`
2. `.then` is then called on `runAsynch2()` which returns `runAsynch3()` (this return carries on all the way down the chain of returns)
3. finally `.then` is called on the returned `runAsynch3()`

As you can see, this is exactly the same process as what happens in example 2

```
// example 2
runAsync1()
.then(function(data1){
    return runAsync2();
}).then(function(data2){
    return runAsync3();  
}).then(function(data3){
    console.log(data3);
});
```